# How to represent a float as a fraction in YAML?

Tags: floating-point, yaml

Which would come handy when storing periodic numbers, e.g. `2/3` instead of `0.66666...7`. I tried:

```
my_periodic: !decimalfraction "2/3"
```

which raise an error (in `Python 3.7`) as:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2/3'
```

Thank you.